# Python keeps refering to outdated variables

Tags: python, linecache

I have a kinda weird problem, here is my attempt at an explanation:

I'm currently making a program which opens a txt file and then reads a line for that file, using the following command linecache.getline(path,number), after the function is done I then use commmand linecache.clearcache.

If I then change something in the text file it keeps returning the pre-changed line.

Following is the code I'm using (I know it aint really pretty)

```
def SR(Path,LineNumber):    
    returns = lc.getline(Path,LineNumber)      
    x = np.array([])
    y = np.array([])
    words = returns.split()
    for word in words:
        x = np.append([x],[word])

    for i in range(len(x)):
        t = float(x[i])
        y = np.append([y],[t])
    return y
    del x
    del y
    del t
    del words
    lc.clearcache()
```

Comment: `lc.clearcache()` is never invoked, because you placed it after `return`.

Comment: What is the point of using `linecache` if you clear the cache after every line read? Why not just use a regular `open(filename)`/`file.read()` operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing after the `return` statement will ever be executed.  If you want to call `clearcache`, you need to call it before the `return` statement.

Also, as a side note, your `del` statements aren't really going to do anything either, even if they were placed before the `return`.  `del` effectively just decrements the reference counter in the gc, which will happen when the interpreter exits the function scope anyway.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks for the comment about the del statements as well!

Comment: "call it before the return statement" -- or in a `finally` block whose `try` block contains the return statement, in the case where you want to execute `clearcache()` even if something throws. Which in this case is probably only going to happen due to lack of memory, but in general if you're doing cleanup think `try ... finally` or context managers.

Comment: @SteveJessop Good point, though if wrapping in a `try`/`except`, it would probably be prudent to wrap all or almost all of the body of the function.

Comment: @SilasRay: indeed. I'm thinking of something like `returns = lc.getline(Path,LineNumber)` `try:` ... rest of the function up to return ... `finally:` `lc.clearcache()`. Hope that's clear enough given lack of formatting in comments :-) Although as Joel Cornett points out above, there's something odd about clearing the cache so often.

Comment: Ah now it makes more sense, I'll try it out, thanks!